# How come RKObjectManager is not using my registered RKObjectRequestOperation class?

Tags: ios, restkit

I am trying to intercept all HTTP requests made by `[RKObjectManager sharedManager]` with a response status of 401 to present the login view again. To do this, I created my own custom `RKObjectRequestOperation` class and overwrote this method:

```
- (void)setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:(void (^)(RKObjectRequestOperation *, RKMappingResult *))success
                              failure:(void (^)(RKObjectRequestOperation *, NSError *))failure
{
    DDLogVerbose(@"SUCCESS BLOCK"); // THIS DOES NOT PRINT WHEN I MAKE ANY REQUEST

    [super setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^void(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation , RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
        if (success) {
            success(operation, mappingResult);
        }

    } failure:^void(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation , NSError *error) {

        DDLogError(@"ERROR BLOCK"); // THIS DOES NOT PRINT WHEN I MAKE ANY REQUEST

        if (failure) {
            failure(operation, error);
        }

    }];
}
```

After creating my custom class, I then register it with the `[RKObjectManager sharedManager` with this line of code:

```
[sharedManager registerRequestOperationClass:[CustomRKObjectRequestOperation class]];
```

Now, whenever I make a request, `RKObjectManager` doesn't seem to be using my custom `RKObjectRequestOperation` class. This request would not print out the console log from the custom class:

```
  [sharedManager postObject:nil
                       path:@"users/sign_in"
                 parameters:@{@"email": email, @"password": password}
                    success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {}
                    failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {}];
```

These are the methods that I will most likely use to make requests with `RKObjectManager`:

```
– getObject:path:parameters:success:failure:
– postObject:path:parameters:success:failure:
– putObject:path:parameters:success:failure:
– patchObject:path:parameters:success:failure:
– deleteObject:path:parameters:success:failure:
```

How do I make a request with `RKObjectManager` so that it uses my registered custom `RKObjectRequestOperation` class?

---

---

**EDIT: This is what I ended up doing...**

I created a category on `RKObjectManager` to attached on a method that would construct the operation itself rather than relying `RKObjectManager`'s default methods.

```
- (void)enqueueRequestWithRouteName:(NSString *)routeName 
                             object:(id)object 
                         parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters 
                            success:(void (^)(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult))success 
                            failure:(void (^)(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error))failure
{
     // You can do some manipulation to your parameters up here before passing it into the request

     NSMutableURLRequest *request = [self requestWithPathForRouteNamed:routeName object:object parameters:parameters];
     request.timeoutInterval = 30.0;
     YourCustomRKRequestOperationClass *operation = [[YourCustomRKRequestOperationClass alloc] initWithRequest:request responseDescriptors:self.responseDescriptors];

     // more customization for core data stuff
     operation.deletesOrphanedObjects = YES;
     operation.savesToPersistentStore = YES;
     operation.manageObjectContext    = self.managedObjectStore.mainQueueManagedObjectContext;
     operation.managedObjectCache     = self.managedObjectStore.managedObjectCache;
     operation.fetchRequestBlocks     = self.fetchRequestBlocks;

     // This is where the magic happens
     [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:success failure:failure];

     [self enqueueObjectRequestOperation:operation];
}
```

Whenever you want to make a request to a mapped route, you can use this method instead of the other ones.

Comment: I'm having the same issue and created a new [project](https://github.com/NicholasMerrill/RestKit-Bug-Test-101) to try to fix the issue but failed. I've been trying to figure this out on and off for weeks. Any luck on your end @RantriX ?

Comment: @NickM I ended up writing a new method that pretty much uses RKObjectManager other methods to construct the operation itself. Check out the edit to check out the method.